# Play Framework/Scala How can I get the value of a flashed in class into an inputText

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to get the value of a Class property that is passed into an html page using flashing, into a @helper.inputText(FormName("Product"))

So I want to get the value in @product.Name into @helper.inputText(CartForm("Product"))

Here is my HTML Code:

```
    @(products: List[Product], CartForm: Form[Cart])(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)
@import play.api.Play.current
@import play.api.i18n.Messages
@import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
@import play.api.mvc.Flash
@import models.{Cart}
@import helper._


@sidebar = {
<ul>
    <li><a href= browse >Categories</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.asp">Gnomes</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp">Gardening Supplies</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.asp">Outdoor Equipment</a></li>
</ul>
}

@main(Messages("productList.page"))(sidebar){


<div id="pageStart">
</div>

<div style="margin-left: 150px;">
    <div id="homeBanner">
        <a href= "home.scala.html"><img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/banner1.png")" alt="Delivery" style=" padding-bottom: 20px; padding-right: 40px; margin-left: 200px;"/></a>
        <a href= "home.scala.html"><img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/banner2.png")" alt="Delivery" style=" padding-bottom: 20px; padding-right: 40px;"/></a>
        <a href= "home.scala.html"><img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/banner3.png")" alt="Delivery" style=" padding-bottom: 20px; padding-right: 40px;"/></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class ="line"></div>

<div id="content">
    <div class="container_12">
        <div class="title">
            <h2 >Our Gallery <a class="button goCart" href="@routes.CartController.list()">My Cart</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            @for(product <- products) {
                <div class="grid_3">
                    <a href="@routes.Assets.versioned(product.imgL)" class="gal">
                        <div class="img_block">
                            <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned(product.imgS)" alt="" class="img_inner">
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="response">@Messages("item.added")</div>

                    @helper.form(action = routes.BrowseController.save) {
                    <div class="title" name="get">
                        <dt>Name: @product.Name</dt>
                        <dt>Description: @product.description</dt>
                        <dt>Price: @product.price</dt>

                        @helper.inputText(CartForm("Product"), 'value -> "@product.Name")
                        @helper.inputText(CartForm("Quantity"))


                        <input type = "submit" class = "btn-primary" value = '@Messages("add.item")'>

                    </div>
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}
```

Any help you can give would be awesome :)

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Have you tried removing the quotes in `@product.Name` from `@helper.inputText(CartForm("Product"), 'value -> "@product.Name")`

Comment: Yeah Ive tried that, it breaks my website